# Google Drive Daily Email Limit?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

We have a few Google Forms as part of my work. I am using the Form Emailer script so that, when someone fills out the quiz, that person and also a person here in our office will receive an e-mail displaying a summary of their responses.

We just had a meeting and so many more people are filling them out right now. My question is, what is the daily e-mail limit when sending in this way, a custom form script?

Keeping in mind that two e-mails are being sent with each form completion, one to our person and one to the person that filled it out.

I tried to research this but I am getting conflicting information--some sites list the limit using Gmail, for example, but I don't think this is the same thing?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit will depend on the account type that is sending the emails. Since you are sending a message to a respondent (1) and a monitor (1), each of your mails will count as 2 recipients.

Your daily limit will be 100 or 1500 per day.

A script can test your remaining limit by calling [MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#getRemainingDailyQuota%28%29).

[image: screenshot]

Ref [Quota Limits tab](https://script.google.com/dashboard).