# Google Drive Email Recipient Quota

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

Referencing this limit: https://script.google.com/dashboard

We have a few forms through our Google Drive, and I use the FormEmailer script (placed in the script editor) to send out a summary notification to two recipients once someone fills it out.

Occasionally, we will have a meeting/gathering where a whole bunch of people will fill out these forms at once.

I did a good amount of research on this but I am getting conflicting information. Some webpages say you can't increase that limit, some say you can (how? We would be willing to pay). It's not a whole lot of extra e-mail, maybe 200 a day instead of the 100 limit.

I see this page but don't see a way to increase it: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Thanks!

Comment: According to the answer you received for [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473013/google-drive-daily-email-limit), you can increase your quota by getting a Google Apps for Business account.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a service vendor's policy, and has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to increase the limit for Google Apps script.

One possible work around here is to have multiple scripts that perform the same function, and send script1 to some people, and script2 to others or something similar. Alternatively if the two recipients are always the same 2 people, you can consider placing them in a group, and sending the email to the group instead, which counts as sending to only 1 person (Thus doubling your current limit).